# RegEx: Find zero at end of string

Tags: regex

What is a regEx to find a zero at the end of a string?

For instance, I want it to find the 0 in 32.20, but not the 0 in 302.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to match the zero in 30.1, it’s `0(?=\.|$)`. Else, it’s just `0$`

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

The right one would be:

```
0$
```

Answer (score 1):

`/0$/` or `/.*0$/` if you need the whole string that ends with a zero.  Here a working [example](http://rubular.com/r/lMam7PA3Xh) on Rubular.