# RegEx: Find zero preceded by decimal point at end of string

Tags: regex, coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx: Find zero at end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737676/regex-find-zero-at-end-of-string)

For example:

I DO want to find the 0 in 32.20
I DON'T want to find the 0 in 320 or 302

Thank you!

Comment: There are lots of incompatible regex implementations. Which one are you using?

Comment: Exact duplicate (same user): [RegEx: Find zero at end of string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737676/regex-find-zero-at-end-of-string)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate. I forgot to add in "after a decimal" last time. I decided not to edit the question but to write a new one because I already had a few answers.

Comment: @Peter, I'm using the reReplace function in Coldfusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the returned match to include the 0, but not the '.', even though you want to make sure the '.' is there. In that case, you need a lookbehind group:

```
(?<=\.\d*?)\d$
```

That should do it, depending on what regex engine you're using.

[Here's some reference info on lookarounds.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

**UPDATE:**

Apparently lookbehind isn't supported by ColdFusion, but you can use Java's regex engine instead. Use the pattern I posted above, and see the answer to **[this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046437/regex-find-content-question)** for how to apply the Java regex engine. That should do the trick.

Note: Double check that `\d` is valid syntax for numeric characters, or you could just use `[0-9]`. Also, depending on how the pattern string is getting passed around, you may need to double the backslashes:

```
"(?<=\\.\\d*?)\\d$"
```

Comment: My regEx engine doesn't recognize that regEx :(

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, this should work with practically all RegEx implementations:

```
[.].*0$
```

You can do better with the Perl like:

```
\.\d*?0$ # A decimal point, followed by some number of digits ending with a 0
```

..., but this syntax may or may not work depending on your RegEx engine:

Comment: The issue is that both those options remove the other digits after the decimal point also. I just want to remove the 0 at the end, not any digits before it.