# Remove string if it is only last part

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
         A      B
 mediafile      1
 filemedia      1
media time      1
time media      1
```

How do I remove the word "media" only if it is the last string in the column. Final Output:

```
         A      B
 mediafile      1
      file      1
media time      1
     time       1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex, `$` means "end of the string", so `media$` will match `media` only if it is immediately followed by the end of the string.

Use `gsub` for find/replace:

```
your_data$A = gsub(pattern = "media$", replacement = "", x = your_data$A)
```

R uses regex the same as any other language, so in the future I'd recommend searching SO for something like "[regex] at end of string", which turned up [this question, from which you probably could have generalized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4737676/903061).